# Vim-devicons not working at all

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, linux-ubuntu, plugin-devicons

I tried installing [vim-devicons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons) to be used with nerdtree(using vim-plugin). I tried [devicons FAQ](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/wiki/FAQ-&-Troubleshooting#why-isnt-it-working-how-come-i-dont-see-any-icons), everything is fine except "check if you are able to see the characters, from ex mode:", i tried running

`:echo g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesDefaultSymbol`

But this command gives no icons result.

Also it says that devicons is to be used with [NerdFonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts), I had trouble installing that. Can anybody guide me through the commands used to install [regular ubuntu font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Ubuntu/Regular/complete) on my ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’m going to vote to close this question, since it’s about font installation more than vi/vim, but please stick around and don’t let that discourage you! There’s a lot to learn about the editor from this site.

Comment: Alright,  no issues!

Answer (score 3):

Installing [Nerd fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Ubuntu/Regular/complete) for my ubuntu 18.04 ***worked***. As the devicons [FAQ](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/wiki/FAQ-&-Troubleshooting) page said, it was designed for nerd fonts.

Comment: If I install that font, would my `gruvbox` color scheme be affected in any way?